# Mercurial and SVN side by side in same working directory?

Tags: svn, mercurial

Our environment currently uses SVN. I would like to commit alot more often, but I don't want to break any of the main branches. Personally I love mercurial much much more than SVN. If I hg init a repository in my SVN working copy would any issues arise if I just commit into the mercurial repository on a regular basis and committed working revisions into the SVN branch?

Our environment is not currently setup such that each developer has their own SVN branch, and so this is not a viable solution currently.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There will not be any problem with having Mercurial and Subversion share a working folder.  Subversion keeps its files in `.svn` folders while Mercurial keeps its files in a `.hg` folder at the top level.

For convenience, you may consider adding a `.svn/` entry to your `.hgignore` file so you don't accidentally commit `.svn` folders in your Mercurial repository.

That being said.  You do not necessarily need to use Subversion at all.  Mercurial can interface with Subversion without a subversion client.  See [Working with Subversion](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/WorkingWithSubversion).

Comment: don't forget to set svn:ignore to ignore the .hg directory. But I agree with you, this works fine.